EXCEL: How to extract a selection of data from a chart, based on filtered name
I am looking for help regarding a tool I'm creating in Microsoft Excel.
Context: I have a list of projects in one sheet, assigned to various people.
The goal is to have a macro that will look through the entire list, based on a given name, then return a list of information about each project they are running.
To give a visual:

And I need to create a solution that will return separate batches of information about each project the selected person is doing:

EDIT: To clarify further, the goal is a solution that, when I input a specific Assignee name in a cell, the system will pull all of their projects from the main chart, and return a list of charts, each with the project information filled in.
As an example, if I write "John" in the cell in question, excel will create two charts, each with information about the project from the respective row (Market, Deadline, Project Name, etc.).
I have considered making separate macros for pulling data for each of the projects manually, by using Index, Match functions, but I feel that is a rather crude option.
Can you help me find the most optimal solution for this?

Where does the assignee come from, it's not in the first table.  Also can you share what you have attempted so far? Please edit the question itself to provide this information.

Sorry, about that, I corrected the first image. That "Reporter" was meant to be "Assignee".

Can you post a desired output? The selected person is always the assignee?

Apologies again, I have edited a more detailed goal. Hopefully it helps.

This is how I would personally approach the problem through VBA. I would create a button to trigger the Sub, or add a worksheet event which executes the Sub when the "Assignee" value is changed (see references below).
Option Explicit

Sub genPrjList()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Data")
Dim wsPrj As Worksheet: Set wsPrj = wb.Sheets("Report")
Dim arr As Variant, i As Long, NewProj As Long, assign_nme As String
Dim data_lr As Long, proj_lr As Long

' Set Last Row values
data_lr = wsData.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
proj_lr = wsPrj.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row

' Remove any existing projects
If proj_lr > 1 Then
    wsPrj.Rows("5:" & proj_lr).Delete
End If

' Get assignee name
assign_nme = wsPrj.Range("B1").Value

' Put Project list into an array
arr = wsData.Range("A2:E" & data_lr)

' Loop through the array and identify assignee projects
NewProj = 5  ' Starting row for Project List
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 3) = assign_nme Then
        wsPrj.Cells(NewProj, 1).Value = "Project Name"      ' Add Title
        wsPrj.Cells(NewProj, 2).Value = arr(i, 1)           ' Get Value from Array
        NewProj = NewProj + 1                               ' Move to Next Row
        wsPrj.Cells(NewProj, 1).Value = "Deadline"          ' Repeat as above
        wsPrj.Cells(NewProj, 2).Value = arr(i, 2)
        NewProj = NewProj + 1
        wsPrj.Cells(NewProj, 1).Value = "Reporter"
        wsPrj.Cells(NewProj, 2).Value = arr(i, 5)
        NewProj = NewProj + 1
        wsPrj.Cells(NewProj, 1).Value = "Market"
        wsPrj.Cells(NewProj, 2).Value = arr(i, 4)
        NewProj = NewProj + 2       ' Prepare for a new project entry
    End If
Next i

If NewProj = 5 Then
    MsgBox "No projects found for assignee " & assign_nme    ' Error capture for no projects
End If

End Sub

Notes:

The A1000 for the last row values would need to be altered depending on the size of your data
The sheet names of Data and Report would also need to be altered to suit your naming convention
An additional subroutine could be added to conduct any formatting requirements during the For loop

References

Microsoft documentation for Arrays here
Microsoft documentation for executing a macro on cell change here

